# Post JSON data to Sql Server report services 2016 with web api

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, asp.net-web-api2, ssrs-2016

I am trying to post JSON data from web app to SQL Server reporting services 2016.
So far I was able to create stored procedure in SQL server to read file with json data and convert it to table format. In SSRS, I am using that stored procedure as data set for report.

Now I need to substitute file as data source to JSON POST data from front end and trigger SSRS to produce report with that data.

I think it is doable by sending JSON data as string to SQL server, convert in SQL server to table, send table to front end, then send that table to SSRS to produce report.

However, I saw solution for using XML and Web API in SSRS:  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/986958/SSRS-Report-Integration-With-Web-Api
It is possible to do the same with JSON and Web API when I will use data from the web page directly and remove SQL Server step?